# Create a pager with "Yesterday", "Monday", "Sunday" etc

Tags: views, datetime, paging

I have a view which through contextual filters show content created on the current day, and I would like to add a pager to allow users to go back in time one day at a time.

Say we visit the site on a Tuesday. So when viewing today's posts there is one link to the left which says "Yesterday" and no link to the right (since there are no future posts), and when this link is clicked we are show yesterdays content (Monday). The links are now "Sunday" to the left and "Today" to the right. Again we click the left link and are shown the content created on Sunday, and the links now show "Saturday" to the left and "Yesterday" to the right.

I've tried using exposed filters but they only output drop downs and only let me sort by asc/desc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Contextual range filter module ( https://drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter ) seems to be the most suitable option as per the above requirement, or you can try the views day of week module ( https://drupal.org/project/views_dow ).

I have created a view for day archive by using the contextual filter of view (without using the above modules) as below below:
[image]

but as your requirement seems to be creating a archive on the basis of week day therefore the best would be to use the above(Contextual range filter module, or the view day of week module), and than you can found the filter in the contextual filter of your view.

Comment: @user14419 Has the above solution worked for you, or if you found some better solution than please share. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible. Just create a new views pager plugin as the default ones:

http://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_pager.inc/group/views_pager_plugins/7

I will need some custom coding to figure out the day of the week but it seems not really hard.